# How to resolve conflict between jquery-1.7.2.min.js and jquery.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, jquery-selectors

I am using **jquery-1.7.2.min.js** and jquery.min.js in my project.

jquery-1.7.2.min.js is on my master page like this:

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Now on my another page i want to use this 2 js files:

```
<script src="~/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/kendo.all.min.js.js"></script>
```

i have done this to resolve error:

```
<script src="~/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="~/kendo.all.min.js.js"></script>
```

**ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

Note:i cant remove jquery-1.7.2.min.js file because some functionality doesnt work when removing it.

Could anybody help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Why not using only newest jq version? You can use jQuery migrate or update relevant plugins   http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: @A.Wolff:will it works for both jquery 1.7 and jquery.min??

Comment: But to which version point `jquery.min`??? And why don't you use more recent bootstrap.js version instead?

Comment: It is bad practice to mix different versions of any script. How do you expect the code to resolve which version of jQuery to use? Either update your code to work with the version of jQuery that Kendo requires you to use or download a version of Kendo that works with jQuery 1.7.2, then remove the `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` reference.

Comment: @Brett:kendo are using jquery.min.js only for kendo.min.js as described on their official sites and i cant found kendo.min for jquery 1.7.2

Comment: @A.Wolff:i required jquery.min.js for kendo.min.js

Comment: I have resolved that error.Thank you so much to all of you